# From where did we get the equation for the angle between two slopes

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

So we have two lines $p$ and $q$. The angle between the positive $x$ axis and $p$ is $\alpha$ and the angle between the positive $x$ axis and $q$ is $\beta$- So the angle between the two lines is $\delta = \alpha - \beta$

However the equation giving this angle is : $\tan(\phi) = \frac{k_1 - k_2}{1 + k_1k_2}$

Where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are the coefficients (gradient) of the two lines.

Where did we get the equation $\tan(\phi) = \frac{k_1 - k_2}{1 + k_1k_2}$ from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $k_1 = \tan \alpha$ and $k_2 = \tan \beta$, this is just the difference of angles formula for $\tan$.  This formula would be derived in almost any pre-calculus or trig text.  Here's a derivation online:

https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/trigonometry/trigonometric-identities/tangent-identities

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the difference formula for tangent. Because the gradient of a (nonvertical) line is the tangent of the angle it makes with positive $x$ axis.

Note it only works if $k_1k_2 \neq -1$ since if $-1$ the lines are perpendicular and difference of angles is $90$ degrees where $\tan$ not defined.